# I want to track my position and also mark a fixed position on the same map

Tags: html, geolocation, marker

I am trying to build a simple page that shows the position of the user in relation to a fixed position on a map.  I have been able to copy and modify some code to track the position of the user, but am unsure of how to add a marker at a fixed position, (say -38.100 +145.500) on the same map.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So far, I have the following....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #map { width:100%; height:150px; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var marker;
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            var timeoutVal = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
                displayPosition, 
                displayError,
                { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: timeoutVal, maximumAge: 0 }
            );
        }
        else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");
        }
        function displayPosition(position) {            
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            var options = {
                zoom: 18,
                center: pos,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
            // Remove the current marker, if there is one
            if (typeof(marker) != "undefined") marker.setMap(null);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                icon: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/Bluedot.png',
                title: "User location"
            });

        }
        function displayError(error) {
            var errors = { 
                1: 'Permission denied',
                2: 'Position unavailable',
                3: 'Request timeout'
            };
            alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Kind regards

Day

Answer (score 0):

You already have the code to add a marker there -

Setting a position

```
     var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
```

And to set a marker

```
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map,
            icon: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/Bluedot.png',
            title: "User location"
        });
```

if you give different latitude and longitude to the pos variable - then the marker would appear in a different position...

Comment: Yes, I wanted to have two markers on the same map.  One like the one I already have on the map that marks my location and another that marks the location of a given object (at say 38.100 +145.500).

Comment: you see the line that says var pos = new google.maps.LatLng ? change that line! - put those coordinates in the parenthesis and see what happens!

Comment: Yes, that gives me a marker that marks the position of the fixed co-ordinates, which I have been able to achieve too. BUT I wanted to get both on the SAME map.  So the user can see their current position AND the position of the given object.

Comment: then add them both! put the code for one and then put the code for other - give them different variable names - or define them with the same in different scopes... if you still don't get it I'll make an example...